# AJAX request to PHP file, PHP file does not receive

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a AJAX request to a PHP file. The PHP file does not receive the request.

I'm using the following code:

register.php:

```
$('#button_step1').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../core/views/cp/test.php',
            data: { message: 'works' },

            success: function(resp) {
                alert(resp);
            }
        });
        $('.step1 input').prop('disabled', true);
        window.location.replace("http://10.0.0.13/core/views/cp/test.php");
    });
```

test.php:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['message'];

?>
```

The message I get after I get redirected to test.php, "Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\views\cp\test.php on line 3".

### Issue 2:

When I `require_once` my `register_view.php` which includes the AJAX request into my `register.php` and let it send a AJAX request to the `register.php` file, it will show me the `alert()` which has all data from the whole PHP file, where it should only show 'works'.

Code,

register.php:

```
<?php

require_once '../core/init.php';

$_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];
echo $_SESSION['message'];

require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/cp/register_view.php';
```

register_view.php:

```
$('#button_step1').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../core/views/cp/test.php',
            data: { message: 'works' },

            success: function(resp) {
                alert(resp);
            }
        });
        $('.step1 input').prop('disabled', true);
        //window.location.replace("http://10.0.0.13/core/views/cp/test.php");
    });
```

Comment: Remove the `window.location.replace()` part.

Comment: How would I check if the request is received on the `test.php` file?

Comment: It's in your `success` function parameter `resp`

Comment: Alright. That seems to be working alright. But there's another issue, let me add it to my post.

Comment: Note that you're not sending the datatype (for example: `dataType: "html"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/cp/register_view.php';` // you are loading view there. you have to do something like this

```
 $a= $_POST['message'];
print_r(json_encode($a));exit;
```

Comment: It still doesn't show me anything on the `register.php` page. Just `null` from the `print_r()`.

Comment: are you getting value there at php ??

Comment: I don't understand your question. Sorry.

Comment: is php function is being called from your ajax ..

what you see on console when you do `console.log(resp);`

Comment: It's blank, nothing logged